# Finding all prime $p$ for which there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $p^n+1$ is a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cubics

$p=7~(n=1)$ is a solution. But how to prove that there are not any other solutions?

Comment: $7+1$ is a square of a positive integer??

Comment: I'd say $p=2,n=3$ is a solution

Comment: The only positive cube that's one less than a square is eight. There's probably no positive 5th power, 7th power, 9th power, etc., that's one less than a square.

Comment: $p=3, n=1$ is a solution.

Comment: Care to engage with the answers and comments that have been posted, Jay?

Comment: Yeah. Just now checked up the answers and comments and yes my question is wrong.. its about p^n+1 being a perfect cube and not perfect square :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are trying to solve:

$$p^{n}+1=q^2$$

$$p^{n}=(q-1)(q+1)$$

This means that:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix}
q-1=p^{\beta}\\ 
q+1=p^{\alpha} \\ 
\alpha>\beta,  \alpha+\beta =n
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Subtracting the $2$ equations:

$$p^{\alpha}-p^{\beta}=2$$

$$p^{\beta}(p^{\alpha-\beta}-1)=2$$

Since the two factors on the LHS are both integers we have that $p^{\beta}|2$, that is to say $(p,\beta)=(2,1)$. So $p^{\alpha-\beta}-1=2^{\alpha-1}-1=1$ which implies that $\alpha=2$. So $$(p,q,n)=(2,3,3)$$

:)

Answer (score 2):

$p^n+1=a^2$ than $p^n=a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$. If $a-1=1$ than $a=2$ and we have $p=3,n=1, a=2$. If $a>2$ we get that difference between 2 divisors of $p^n$ equal 2. $p^k-p^l=p^l(p^{k-l}-1)=2$. So $p=2, l=1, k=2$, or $p=2, n=3, a=3$

Comment: Am actually sorry the problem is to find all p such that p^n+1 is a perfect CUBE and nor a perfect square. Anyways thanks for all those answers :)